# File is getting autodownloaded in internet explorer on reload of the page. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular2-forms

I have below anchor tag in html for downloading file.

```
 <a [href]="myFileUrl"
              class="u-text--document"
           download="myfile.csv"><span>Title of the Excel document (6.8MB)</span></a>
```

and this method i am calling on ngOninit(),

```
 // subscribe to my file content
  getMyFileTemplate(): any {
    this.myService.getMyFile().subscribe((response) => {
      const FileContent = response;
      const blob = new Blob([FileContent], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
      if (navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf('.NET') > 0) {
        this.myFileUrl= window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'employees');
      } else {
        this.myFileUrl= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This method works fine in Google chrome, **but in IE , on page reload, its downloading file automatically without even clicking on the link**. Can anyone please help to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Call this function on click event of anchor tag instead of ngOnInit()

```
<a [href]="myFileUrl"  class="u-text--document" download="myfile.csv"(click)="getMyFileTemplate()">
    <span>Title of the Excel document (6.8MB)</span>
</a>
```